# Is it possible in Redmine to change the email emission address to the address of the issue assigner?

Tags: email, redmine

In the settings.yml file there's a setting:

```
mail_from:
   default: redmine@example.net
```

Is there a way to change this so that it reflects the email of the assigner instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use my plugin:
https://github.com/darioo/redmine_author_notification_emails

It change default sender to Author of a post and add new email headers: Sender na Reply-to set to Setting.mail_from

Answer (score 2):

I think it is impossible without patching Redmine (= there is no easy way).

Look at the [`app/models/mailer.rb`](https://github.com/redmine/redmine/blob/master/app/models/mailer.rb). This file build mailers. In method [`mail`](https://github.com/redmine/redmine/blob/master/app/models/mailer.rb#L371) "from" is defined as `Setting.mail_from`.

If you would like to change the behavour (for example for [`issue_add`](https://github.com/redmine/redmine/blob/master/app/models/mailer.rb#L31)). You can try to write a plugin to patch a result of this method.

Idea is following: standard workflow for this method return an object `mail` with defined settings, you can patch the result of method `issue_add` and redefined some of them (I am not sure if it possible but I believe it might be so).

I think you can use `alias_method_chain` to patch methods.

PS I hope it will help you